# Japanese writings in Brazil

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, history

I've seen these writings in the ground of Brazil.

I've already tried to translate it with my friend but there are some complex kanji that we don't know.

I'm very curious to know what they say, can someone translate it? I have four pictures, if the writings are not legible I can try to edit the photos and make them more legible.

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

[image: Third Picture]

[image: Fourth Picture]

Comment: We don't do translations here. I'm having some trouble reading it, but the characters I make out are:  汗のない / [illegible to me] 会 は　[illegible to me]落だ。

Comment: Ahh yes that does appear to be accurate. Couldn't see the strokes on the darker gray (and not being a native speaker had no intuition on that one).

Comment: That would be 堕落{だらく}, not 墜落{ついらく}

Comment: It looks to me as 汗のない社会は堕落だ

Comment: Maybe from this? >>> 「愛のない社会は暗黒であり、汗の無い社会は堕落である・・・野中広務」　http://homepage3.nifty.com/hirose/text/word/index.html

Comment: げっ、「漢詩より」だって！http://www.ohira-sh.open.ed.jp/index.php/2009-11-17-07-53-15/57-2009-10-27-07-24-27/2009-10-27-07-25-00/127-2011-09-12-07-32-29

Comment: This seems to be one of those quotes everybody attributes to somebody else. (I have also seen it attributed to 蓮沼門三.) I bet if we look hard enough somebody will attribute it to Lincoln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be 汗のない社会は堕落だ, which is a variation on 「愛なき人生は暗黒なり。汗なき社会は堕落なり。」Google tells me this is a quote from [前田又兵衛](http://systemincome.com/main/kakugen/tag/%E5%89%8D%E7%94%B0%E5%8F%88%E5%85%B5%E8%A1%9B). Something like "A life without love is darkness. A society without effort is corruption."